# Date formatting in a grid

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

I'm trying to display a date column in grid like this: "dd-mm-yyyy". In dbf table, the date is stored in this format: "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss" in a character field.
The grid is created from this cursor:

```
select id,beginningDate,endDate,cnp from doc ORDER BY id desc INTO CURSOR myCursor
```

I wish something like this:

```
select id,convert(beginningDate, Datetime,"dd-mm-yyyy"),endDate,cnp from doc ORDER BY id desc INTO CURSOR myCursor
```

Comment: I realize you may not be able to change this, but there's no reason to store a datetime in a character field. If you had a datetime field, then this would be simple.

Answer (score 0):

Fox doesn't have a builtin function called `convert()`, nor can it handle your non-standard date/time string format directly.

A quick and dirty way to convert a string `foo` in the given format ("YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss") to a date/time value is

```
ctot("^" + chrtran(foo, "T", " "))
```

The caret marks the input as the locale-independent standard format, which differs from the input format only by having a space instead of a 'T'.

You can extract the date portion from this via the `ttod()` function, or simply extract only the date portion from the string and convert that:

```
ctod("^" + left(foo, 10))
```

Fox's controls - including those in a grid - normally use the configured Windows system format (assuming that `set("SYSFORMATS") == "ON"`); you can override this by playing with the `SET DATE` command.

There seems to be no mask-based date formatting option as in most other languages. `dtoc()` and `ttoc()` don't take format strings, `transform()` takes a format string but blithely ignores it for date values.

Answer (score 0):

I am with Tamar on this subject, you should have used a datetime field instead.

Since you are storing it like this anyway, you can 'convert' to datetime using the built-in cast function (or ttod(ctot()) in versions older than VFP9 - in either case you don't need to remove T character):

```
select id, ;
  Cast(Cast("^"+beginningDate as datetime) as date) as beginningDate, ;
  endDate,cnp ;
  from doc ;
  ORDER BY id desc ;
  INTO CURSOR myCursor ;
  nofilter
```

In grid or any other textbox control, you can control its display style using DateFormat property. ie:

```
* assuming it is Columns(2). 11 is DMY
thisform.myGrid.Columns(2).SetAll('DateFormat', 11)
```

Comment: Note: leaving the 'T' character instead of substituting a blank works only with VFP7 and newer.

Comment: @DarthGizka, also cast doesn't work before VFP9 but even that one is 9 years old.I didnt see in question a version was mentioned.

Comment: Right enough. However, when you're working with a legacy system then you can't pick your favourite Fox version... And nowadays pretty much everything that has to do with Fox falls under legacy. Just a few months ago I came across FPW 2.6 (I shit you not) and I know of active commercial operations based on Clipper and others based on FPD. Time runs differently for legacy systems.